# Trigger external API Calls with Cloudwatch Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-systems-manager

I am looking for a solution to make a POST Request to an External API when the state of an EC2 Instance changes. I want to use Cloudwatch so that I can pass the InstanceId to the API with the Input Transformer option.

Is there a way to do this without involving Lambda? (upstream requirement)
Perhaps with an SSM Automation?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) at lifecycle scripts. Lambda is likely the easiest way, but using scripts on the instance might work if the instance is up / available.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the *CloudWatch events* to **SNS Topic** or **SQS Queue** and have a subscriber somewhere that will do the API call when the event happens. However you still need to host the subscriber somewhere, give it the permissions to subscribe to the topic / queue, etc.

It would be *much easier* to use Lambda with a simple IAM Role. Can you elaborate why it isn't an option? Why would you not use the best suited tool for the job at hand?